# Shell programing printf %s

Tags: linux

need some help on using printf %s

This is part of my code

```
getspace=`expr 50-$getlength`;

#the space is between var1 & var2 
printf "%s %20s\n" "$var1" "$var2"
```

I want swap the value %20s with getspace result.. means if getspace is 15 for this loop it will be %15s, and if getspace is 50 for next element, it willbe %50s

How do i swap in the dynamic variable for printf

I tried and it doesnt work

```
printf "%s %$getspaces\n" "$var1" "$var2"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf "%s %${getspace}s\n" "$var1" "$var2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%s %*s\n" "$var1" "$getspace" "$var2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the line

```
getspace=`expr 50-$getlength`
```

should be

```
getspace=`expr 50 - $getlength`
```

and then,

```
printf "%s %${getspace}s\n" "$var1" "$var2"
```

should work, as it has worked for me.